# Scanned Letter of Recommendation versus Saved as PDF

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

Question from my professor :

While filling in a request for Recommendation Letter, portal said

> Please upload PDF File. Do not print recommendation and scan as PDF

My professor had printed the letter on college letterhead, signed it, scanned and saved as PDF well in advance.
And now he is confused about what should be done.

Kindly advise
1. Upload the Scanned PDF
2. Save the letter from docx to PDF and upload. This document won't have letterhead or the signature.

I was under the impression that most universities use OCR to process letter, hence scanned documents would suffice.

Comment: Your professor should follow the instructions given.  I don't understand why this is hard.

Comment: He is confused since, many places demand the letter to be on letterhead to verify that the its from the correct source

Comment: Is there no electronic version of the letterhead that can be included in the document before saving/printing?

Comment: No. He looked for the same. But the college doesn't have it. Would it be bad if he just uploaded the scanned copy? He says that OCR Readers would be able to convert it easily.

Comment: Don't ask us to guess what the recipient of the letter wants. Ask the recipient of the letter.

Comment: Contact the "contact person", whether that's an HR person or a group leader who'll be reading the letters. That's why there is contact information on most job ads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I called the University in question. They asked not to upload scanned copies as few professors use Screen Readers for documents, and it may not work properly for scanned copies.

She did not give me any concrete information regarding letterhead requirement.

When I suggested the two-pages PDF idea, she said she's not sure if that would do. She has asked me to ask my professor to upload the two paged PDF, email her that he has done so with the applicant's info i.e. my name. And then she would have someone verify if the format is okay.

So I'm guessing if the format is not okay, my professor would have to do more work regarding my letter.

**Edit :**
My professor pulled some strings, and got the original image of the letterhead and added it to a docx template. And he will use a scanned image of his signature to sign the PDF using Adobe Reader. I guess this should be sufficient.
Feeling hopeful.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please refrain from using answers as a form of commenting the question, for that purpose you can edit your question and add more information.

Comment: @posdef Looks like an answer to me. The question was "What should I do?" We said, "Ask the people you're sending the letter to" and the answer is, "I asked those people and they said do X, Y, Z."

Comment: @DavidRicherby my first reaction was to see this answer as a comment, adding on information to a narrative, hence my comment.

Comment: The answer here is "contact the school and work around the stupid requirement", which seems to have worked for the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The instructions seem simple enough for your professor to follow. However, if still in doubt, you could contact the University concerned and see if you could come to a conclusion regarding this matter.

Comment: So it would be okay if the uploaded letter didn't have the letterhead and signature?

Comment: @ChanchalR.Kariwala That is what you would have to confirm with the University which set up this constraint.

Comment: _The instructions seem simple enough for your professor to follow._ I disagree. The instructions are logically inconsistent (a scanned PDF is a PDF), confusing, impose a needless burden on busy people performing a voluntary service, and fail to anticipate a reasonably common situation (a professor who doesn't have or doesn't know where to get an electronic version of his institution's letterhead). I can't blame the professor for being annoyed and wanting more precise instructions.

Comment: @DanRomik, thank you for understanding our confusion.

Comment: If you have time to ask the institution the letter is going to, please do.  Some ideas occur to me: (1) scan a plain piece of letterhead, and scan the signature.  PDF readers, such as foxit, make it easy to add an electronic signature.  (2) just save the docx as a pdf and send it without letterhead or signature.  (3) send both versions.

Comment: @aparente001 I'd say that's a brilliant idea.

Comment: @aparente001, it really is a very good idea! I could ask my Professor to merge the two pdfs, and make a two pages PDF, wherein the first page would be the normal docx to PdF page and the second page could be the scanned one.

Comment: @ChanchalR.Kariwala Hold on. I don't think aparente001 meant to *merge them*. Confirm before hand. In any way, it would be better to consult the institution the LoR is to be sent.

Comment: I have written them an email since it's the weekend. I will also call them during office hours on Monday. I don't want to create a mess in haste. @aparente001, could you explain further?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac - Which idea did you like?  The electronic signature?  Chanchal, I was thinking you might as well send them both versions, and if they don't allow multiple submissions, I was thinking you could merge them with something like PDF Split & Merge, but it sounds like Ébe didn't think it's a good idea.... // At any rate, phoning on Monday sounds good.

Comment: Yes, @aparente001, I also feel that merging do seem to be a good idea, but all this would become clear as soon as Chanchal receives a clarification from the Institution.

Comment: @aparente001, thank you for putting my mind at ease :)

Comment: @ChanchalR.Kariwala - Glad you're feeling better; keep us posted.

Comment: Yes @aparente001. We're interested to know how it goes, Chanchal.